# PyTorch's dataloader "too many open files" error when no files should be open

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

So this is a minimal code which illustrates the issue:

This is the Dataset:

```
class IceShipDataset(Dataset):
    BAND1='band_1'
    BAND2='band_2'
    IMAGE='image'

    @staticmethod
    def get_band_img(sample,band):
        pic_size=75
        img=np.array(sample[band])
        img.resize(pic_size,pic_size)
        return img

    def __init__(self,data,transform=None):
        self.data=data
        self.transform=transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)  

    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        sample=self.data[idx]
        band1_img=IceShipDataset.get_band_img(sample,self.BAND1)
        band2_img=IceShipDataset.get_band_img(sample,self.BAND2)
        img=np.stack([band1_img,band2_img],2)
        sample[self.IMAGE]=img
        if self.transform is not None:
                sample=self.transform(sample)
        return sample
```

And this is the code which fails:

```
PLAY_BATCH_SIZE=4
#load data. There are 1604 examples.
with open('train.json','r') as f:
        data=f.read()
data=json.loads(data)

ds=IceShipDataset(data)
playloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(ds, batch_size=PLAY_BATCH_SIZE,
                                          shuffle=False, num_workers=4)
for i,data in enumerate(playloader):
        print(i)
```

It gives that weird open files error in the for loop…
My torch version is 0.3.0.post4

If you want the json file, it is available at Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/statoil-iceberg-classifier-challenge)

I should mention that the error has nothing to do with the state of my laptop:

```
yoni@yoni-Lenovo-Z710:~$ lsof | wc -l
89114
yoni@yoni-Lenovo-Z710:~$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
791958
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the number of workers? If you are running on a shared compute device it may be that it does not allow for multiple processes.

Comment: Actually I've tried num_workers=0 , in which case there's a different error at i=25 for no obvious reason(RuntimeError: tried to construct a tensor from a float sequence, but found an item of type str at index (1)
), However it's confusing me: Why would accessing a list which is shared in memory not work? I mean, isn't it the point of the Dataset and Dataloader abstractions? :P Plus, why does it complain about the number of open files?

Comment: A process is associated with file descriptors, your compute environment presumably has a limit (see `ulimit`) to the number of possible descriptors to prevent resource abuse. The other error you are seeing is probably a bug in your code but now you can debug it at least.

Comment: Well,I've added the state of my machine to the main question. When it comes to a bug - I've posted the code which causes the bug, so you are more than welcomed to show it to me- I don't see it. I have a workaround anyways, but i want to know what really happened here so that in the future I can save time - I def will use pytorch as my main dl framework!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know how to fix the error, but I don't have a complete explanation for why it happens.

**First, the solution**: you need to make sure that the image data is stored as `numpy.array`s, when you call `json.loads` it loads them as python `list`s of `float`s. This causes the `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` to individually transform each float in the list into a `torch.DoubleTensor`.

Have a look at `default_collate` in `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` - your `__getitem__` returns a `dict` which is a mapping, so `default_collate` gets called again on each element of the `dict`. The first couple are `int`s, but then you get to the image data which is a `list`, i.e. a `collections.Sequence` - this is where things get funky as `default_collate` is called on each element of the list. This is clearly not what you intended. I don't know what the assumption in `torch` is about the contents of a `list` versus a `numpy.array`, but given the error it would appear that that assumption is being violated.

The fix is pretty trivial, just make sure the two image bands are `numpy.array`s, for instance in `__init__`

```
def __init__(self,data,transform=None):
    self.data=[]
    for d in data:
        d[self.BAND1] = np.asarray(d[self.BAND1])
        d[self.BAND2] = np.asarray(d[self.BAND2])
        self.data.append(d)
    self.transform=transform
```

or after you load the json, what ever - doesn't really matter where you do it, as long as you do it.

---

Why does the above results in `too many open files`?

I don't know, but as the comments pointed out, it is likely to do with interprocess communication and lock files on the two queues data is taken from and added to.

*Footnote: the `train.json` was not available for download from Kaggle due to the competition still being open (??). I made a dummy json file that should have the same structure and tested the fix on that dummy file.*

Comment: For me, putting the following at the start of program solved my problem: `torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy('file_system')`

Comment: Had the same error as OP, but used `torch.tensor` for my labels. Switching to `np.asarray()` solved the issue as answer suggests.